# Passing function to spark: how to pass class parameter to function and avoid unpickle or closure error

Tags: function, apache-spark, closures, pyspark, pickle

code like below:

```
rdd.map(lambda x:myfunc(para1,para2)),

def myfunc(x,para1,para2):
  #para2 is instance of class,like para2 = Httplib.HTTPConnection()
  para2.read()
  return x
```

When I pass function to RDD transaction, with parameter of class object, it will always occure closure or error like 'NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new'.How i can avoid this? how I can use that right way?

Comment: Don't pass objects which are not designed to be serializable?

Comment: I don't know how to serialization for pyspark actually, can you show me more detail?